# Elasticsearch IP is different from the actual IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

Hi guys I am new to ubuntu and elasticsearch. Pls spare me if I sound silly.

I am using windows 8. I installed ubuntu on my Oracle virtual machine software. When I did ifconfig in the terminal I got the following ip

```
> 172.16.49.21
```

I have installed elasticsearch2.3 on my ubuntu OS. I ran the command `./elasticsearch` to start elasticsearch service. At the time of start, I could see the following messages from the terminal:

```
anand@anand-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.3.1/bin$ ./elasticsearch
[2016-04-12 21:14:25,567][INFO ][node                     ] [Fenris Wolf] version[2.3.1], pid[3168], build[bd98092/2016-04-04T12:25:05Z]
[2016-04-12 21:14:25,568][INFO ][node                     ] [Fenris Wolf] initializing ...
[2016-04-12 21:14:26,653][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Fenris Wolf] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-04-12 21:14:26,691][INFO ][env                      ] [Fenris Wolf] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [86gb], net total_space [95gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2016-04-12 21:14:26,692][INFO ][env                      ] [Fenris Wolf] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-04-12 21:14:26,692][WARN ][env                      ] [Fenris Wolf] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-04-12 21:14:29,439][INFO ][node                     ] [Fenris Wolf] initialized
[2016-04-12 21:14:29,439][INFO ][node                     ] [Fenris Wolf] starting ...
[2016-04-12 21:14:29,613][INFO ][transport                ] [Fenris Wolf] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2016-04-12 21:14:29,617][INFO ][discovery                ] [Fenris Wolf] elasticsearch/ltT6fvOEQAWS9NDzZXsNig
[2016-04-12 21:14:32,696][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Fenris Wolf] new_master {Fenris Wolf}{ltT6fvOEQAWS9NDzZXsNig}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-04-12 21:14:32,711][INFO ][http                     ] [Fenris Wolf] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2016-04-12 21:14:32,712][INFO ][node                     ] [Fenris Wolf] started
[2016-04-12 21:14:32,769][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Fenris Wolf] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

From the above terminal output, one could see that the IP and the port in which elasticsearch is running is

```
> 127.0.0.1:9200
```

My questions are

1. why is elasticsearch service not running on the actual IP `172.16.49.21`?
2. What changes will I to make for the service run on the actual IP `172.16.49.21`?
3. If the change is done successfully, will I be able to access elasticsearch on the said IP from my windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch binds to localhost by default. If you want anything else you will need to do some Network configuration as described here in the [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) manual.. You can be new to Ubuntu and Elasticsearch, but you should do some homework before posting to this site with a question such as yours. This came up on the first Google hit.

Whether you can access the VM guest from your windows host has to do with how you set your VM up for networking. I am assuming you're using vbox based on your comments. If you can access Elasticsearch on the guest but not the host make sure the network on your Guest is Bridged and not Nat.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am sorry to disappoint you with such a silly question. I googled and also tried to change 'network.host' before I posted this question, but I was not sure and was worried that I might screw something up.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time add what you've tried and how or if it worked.

Comment: your solution worked for me.Thanks again once again! :)